# Python Requests, Work Proxy and Django REST

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, python-requests

appreciate your help here, thanks in advance.

My Problem:

- I am using Python's Requests module for get/post requests to a Django REST API behind a work proxy. I am unable to get past the proxy and I encounter an error. I have summarised this below:

Using the following code (what I've tried):

```
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {
    "User-Agent": [someGenericUserAgent]
    }

s.trust_env = False

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://[domain]\[userName]:[password]@[proxy]:8080',
    'https': 'https://[domain]\[userName]:[password]@[proxy]:8080'
    }

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = [APIaddress]
os.environ['no_proxy'] = [APIaddress]

r = s.post(url=[APIaddress], proxies=proxies)
```

With this I get an error:

```
... OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))
```

Additional Context:

- This is on a windows 10 machine.
- Work uses a "automatic proxy setup" script (.pac), looking at the script there are a number of proxies that will be automatically assigned depending on the IP address of the machine. All of these proxies I have tried under [proxy] above, with the same error.
- The above works when I am not running through the work network, and I don't use the additional proxy settings (removing proxies=proxies). i.e on my home network.
- I have no issues with a get request via my browser via the proxy to the Django REST API view.

Things I am uncertain about:

1. I don't know if I am using the right [proxy]. Is there a way to verify this? I have tried using [findMyProxy].com sites, using the ip addresses it still doesn't work.
2. I don't know if I am using `[domain]\[userName]` correctly. is a `\` correct? my work does use a domain.
3. I'm certain it is not a requests issue, as trying to do `pip install --proxy http://[domain]\[userName]:[password]@[proxy]:8080 someModule` bares the same 407 error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you can use a browser, you should have proxies configured there. So, you could look them up in Chrome, for example. I suggest trying to do some simple `GET` request using command line and `curl` or `wget` and make sure that proxy is being taken into account (eg. `curl -x your_proxy http://example.com`).

Comment: Hi Marek, thank you for spending the time and getting back to me. I found a solution, your answer helped me here. I did end up using `curl` to determine what the bottle neck was, from this I found my org uses ntlm... see below for how I got to the end game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I came to the solution:

1. I used `curl` to establish a `<200 response>`, after a lot of trial and error, success was:

`$ curl -U DOMAIN\USER:PW -v -x http://LOCATION_OF_PAC_FILE --proxy-ntlm www.google.com`

- Where -U is the domain, user name and password.
- -V is verbose, made it easier for debugging.
- -x is the proxy, in my case the location to the .pac file. Curl automatically determines the proxy IP from the PAC. Requests does not do this by default (that I know of).
- I used curl to determine that my proxy was using ntlm.
- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as an external site to test the proxy auth.
- NOTE: only 1 off `\` between domain and username.

2. Trying to make `request` use ntlm, I found was impossible by default and instead used  `requests-ntlm2`.
3. The PAC file through `request-ntlm2` did not work so I used `pypac` to autodiscover the PAC file then determined the proxy based on the URL.
4. The working code is as follows:

```
from pypac import PACSession

from requests_ntlm2 import (
    HttpNtlmAuth,
    HttpNtlmAdapter,
    NtlmCompatibility
)

username = 'DOMAIN\\USERNAME'
password = 'PW'

# Don't need the following thanks to pypacs
# proxy_ip = 'PROXY_IP'
# proxy_port = "PORT"
# proxies = {
#     'http': 'http://{}:{}'.format(proxy_ip, proxy_port),
#     'https': 'http://{}:{}'.format(proxy_ip, proxy_port)
# }

ntlm_compatibility = NtlmCompatibility.NTLMv2_DEFAULT

# session = requests.Session() <- replaced with PACSession()
session = PACSession()

session.mount(
    'https://',
    HttpNtlmAdapter(
        username,
        password,
        ntlm_compatibility=ntlm_compatibility
    )
)
session.mount(
    'http://',
    HttpNtlmAdapter(
        username,
        password,
        ntlm_compatibility=ntlm_compatibility
    )
)
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(
    username,
    password,
    ntlm_compatibility=ntlm_compatibility
)

# Don't need the following thanks to pypacs
# session.proxies = proxies

response = session.get('http://www.google.com')
```